# ASP How to get a value from HTML column

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic, html-table

I have an ASP page which displays rows of data in an HTML table, after a query to an SQL database. The number of returned rows can vary. I want to add a function so that when i click on a button, I fire off a query to the SQL server database to update a column in that particular row. To do that i will use the primary key from my result set.

The part I am having difficulty with is getting the proper rows ID. What I have wrote so far returns the same ID every time regardless of which row i click on. Sample code below.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td class="bold" colspan="9"><%=vHeading%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tablehead">Id</td>
            <td class="tablehead">WhenPosted</td>
            <td class="tablehead">WhenCreated</td>
            <td class="tablehead">WhenUpdated</td>
            <td class="tablehead">Source</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <%
    DO WHILE NOT stRs.eof
    i = i + 1
    %>
        <tr>
            <td id="pId<%=i%>" class="tablecell"><%=stRs.fields("Id")%></td>
            <td class="tablecell"><%=stRs.fields("WhenPosted")%></td>
            <td class="tablecell"><%=stRs.fields("WhenCreated")%></td>
            <td class="tablecell"><%=stRs.fields("WhenUpdated")%></td>
            <td class="tablecell"><%=stRs.fields("Source")%></td>
            <td id=<%=i%>><input type="button" value="Post" onclick="post();" /></td>       

        </tr>

        <%
        stRs.MoveNext
    LOOP 
    %>

</table>

<script text="text/javascript">
function post() {
  var pId = document.getElementById("pId").innerHTML;

  alert(pId);
}
</script>
```

So i loop through my result set creating rows. For examples-sake, row one will contain ID 1. Row 2 will have ID 2 etc.
If I click on my button which fires off the post method, the alert shows ID 1 every time, no matter the row i click on. I guessed its because i was originally assigning the same ID to the column for each row. I now use a counter variable and assign it to the ID which is creating unique ID's for the columns now, but I'm not sure how to call the function and use the correct ID. Any pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass **I** to the function:

```
<input type="button" value="Post" onclick="post(<%=i%>);" />
```

then

```
<script text="text/javascript">
function post(i) {
  var pId = document.getElementById("pId"+i).innerHTML;

  alert(pId);
}
</script>
```